# JQuery 'Sortable' not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to use the `Sortable` interaction that JQuery has, and it isn't working. I know that, or at least assume, that the library is being imported correctly because I am able to use `draggable`.

Here is the HTML I'm trying to use:

```
<ul class="_ts">
    <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a></li>
    <li><a   class="new_appt" href="#">Open </a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$("._ts").sortable();
$("._ts").disableSelection();
```

When I load the page I get this error in my JS console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'

I have also tried to change the class to an ID, but that doesn't work either. This appears to be a fairly simple implementation, but for whatever reason, it isn't working for me.

I used the docs here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ to implement this, but it doesn't work. As I stated before, I can use the `draggable` feature. To do that I did:

```
$("._ts").draggable();
```

And everything worked as expected. As a note, I am using Wordpress, and to import the JQuery Library I used:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```

I have read that this was all I need to include to use the JQuery UI, is that true? If not what else do I need to add to use this library?

EDIT:

I have tried adding the Sortable Library by doing:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
```

But I still get the same error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Verify if the jqueryui version downloaded, have sortable methods or download the full version from jqueryui like a cdn <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> (This is full version)

Comment: the script getting loaded (jquery-ui-datepicker) may not include the sortable methods.

Comment: Wordpress already has sortable library. You can try to deregister it before register yours, to prevent issues betwen versions.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason using:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
```

Does not work. I had to use the direct link:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my_jquery_ui', "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js", array('jquery'), '1.0', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it can not understand the *$* sign
Try to use *jQuery* instead of *$*.
Or you can wrap the whole code with the function like this:

```
(function ($) {
... //Any code here
}(jQuery)
```

There you can put the code with $